# Can VSTO Addins be built without installing MS Office?

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working on setting up build server for a VSTO Addin project. I am using Jenkins for the same. When I try to build project locally on my machine using MS Build it is building fine. However on server, it gives following error:

`Error  10  Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

I think this should be coming from PIA. Can I install PIA without MS Office installed on machine?

So, my question is it not possible to build VSTO solution without installing the MS Office suite on server?

Answer (score 1):

> I think this should be coming from PIA. Can I install PIA without MS Office installed on machine?

Yes, you are free to install PIAs without MS Office. It will allow to build the project, but at runtime you will get exceptions in the code. PIAs are used for marshalling your property and method calls to the unmanaged code, i.e. COM servers represented by Office applications.

> is it not possible to build VSTO solution without installing the MS Office suite on server?

You are free to build VSTO add-ins on a machine without MS Office installed.

Comment: I am not running the code on the build server. Only for building the DLLs and final installer. So, I will give it a try, I cant find PIA for MS Office 2013. Any hint on that?

Comment: You may get them on a PC with Office 2013 installed. Note, they are generated by VS automatically when you add a reference to the host application. Office 2013 should be installed in that case.